# define different font depending on the compiler

Tags: expl3, documentclass-writing

I am writing a class file and want to use `fontspec` and `unicode-math` if the compiler is `luatex` or `xetex`. If the compiler is `pdftex` I would like to define default fonts like `cmr` and `phv` instead. I am trying to use `\sys_if_engine*` in the `cls`-file but getting the error: sys not defined or somethins like that. Can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that these packages did not use the `\ProvidesPackage` but `\ProvidesExplPackage` so I researched that and found this solution:

```
\newif \if@luatex
\newif \if@xetex

\@luatexfalse
\@xetexfalse

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \sys_if_engine_luatex:T {\@luatextrue}
    \sys_if_engine_xetex:T  {\@xetextrue}
\ExplSyntaxOff

...
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@luatex} \OR \boolean{@xetex}}{
    \RequirePackage{unicode-math}
    \RequirePackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
    \newfontfamily \arial {Arial}
    \setmathfont{Cambria Math}
}{
    % Have not solved this part yet.
}
```